# I want to redirect anyHOST.anyTLD to www.anyHOST.anyTLD

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to find a generic enough modrewrite rule that will acomplish following:

Redirect anyHost.anyTld to www.anyHost.anyTld
Not mess with any other subdomains, for examle other.anyHost.anyTLD should be left alone
Can you help? Does this slow down server too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm no expert on the speed (or lack thereof) of mod_rewrite, but I don't think you would notice any impact on speed.